# Firebase storage rules, Libre Office contentTypes

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I'm trying to write firebase storage rules that allows uploads with some specific extensions. I can't figure out how to write a rule for Libre office files. I've tried:

```
request.resource.contentType.matches('.odt') ||
request.resource.contentType.matches('.ods') ||
request.resource.contentType.matches('.odp') ||
```

and also:

```
request.resource.contentType.matches('application/odt') ||
request.resource.contentType.matches('application/ods') ||
request.resource.contentType.matches('application/odp') ||
```

None of these are working. How to write a rule to load Libre Office files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this Libre Office repo](https://github.com/LibreOffice/core), the [MIME content types](https://github.com/LibreOffice/core/blob/master/solenv/inc/mime.types#L185-L194) for those file extensions are:

| MIME type | Extension |
| --- | --- |
| `application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text` ([IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text)) | `.odt` |
| `application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet` ([IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet)) | `.ods` |
| `application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation` ([IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation)) | `.odp` |

These are "vendor tree" media types, thus they start with `vnd.VENDOR.`. Some extensions, like `application/json` are IANA defined types and do not have this prefix - you normally can't just throw an extension after the `/`.

Your rules would then be:

```
request.resource.contentType.matches('application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text') ||
request.resource.contentType.matches('application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet') ||
request.resource.contentType.matches('application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation') ||
```

Comment: @Dharmaraj Indeed. Answer races are fun.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at properties of files saved by LibreOffice, they look something like this:

[image]

[image]

I looked up for these mime-types and found them in documentation of [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/framework/documentation/mimetypes/mimetypes.html).

Then I tried these security rules and they worked perfectly:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow write: if request.resource.contentType.matches('application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.*');
    }
  }
}
```

I just added a wildcard (`'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.*'`) at the end. I tried with `.odt` and `.ods` files. They were uploaded.